# No Css transition possible

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nice transition for my button. I tested the used mode on an red div, it works! But on my button it would not.

I think it's possibly because of the nested elements, but no tested solution worked.

```css
div.container {   
   max-width: 240px; 
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #cd8102;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 36px;
    background: linear-gradient(#fcbf00, #f39600); /* Standard syntax */
    font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear 0s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background 1s linear 0s;
}
div.container:hover{
 background: linear-gradient(yellow, #f39600); /* Standard syntax */
    width: 300px;
}
div.innerContainer{
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto; /* default value */ 
}
div.box1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 207;
    max-width: 207px;
    /*border: 1px solid red; */
    float: left;
    height: 36px;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
div.box2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
#TextInTheMiddle {
 text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */ 
    height: 36px;       
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.de"  type="submit">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="innerContainer">
       <div class="box1"><span id='TextInTheMiddle'>Langer text macht uns allen freude</span></div>
       <div class="box2"><span><img id="img" src="file:///Y|/Button/images/icons/next.png" height="20" width="20"></span></div>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </a>
```

Do you have any ideas to solve the problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: its not really clear what you want exactly, could you post an image or a fiddle of the working example

Comment: Just a background transiton from the orange gradient to maybe a green gradient on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `background-image` cannot be animated, and css gradients are actually browser rendered images. You can mimic animation on gradients by changing its background position or using opacity

There is an article on animating gradients here:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/

For a list of animateable properties, check http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties